# Uncaught ReferenceError: buscarCancion is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, google-api

Estoy intentando hacer una pequeña pagina donde digite el nombre de una canción cualquiera y Google me devuelva el resultado a través de su API de búsqueda, pero al hacer Clic en el botón buscar, no pasa nada y en consola me sale este mensaje. Que puede estar pasando?:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"
"Uncaught ReferenceError: buscarCancion is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick(index.html:11:67)"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Búsqueda de canción</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Búsqueda de canción</h1>
    <form>
        <label for="txtNombreCancion">Nombre de la canción:</label> <br>
        <input type="text" id="txtNombreCancion" value=""><br>
        <input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="buscarCancion()">
   </form>
   <div id="resultado"></div>

 <script>

    function buscarCancion() {
    // Obtenemos el nombre de la canción del campo de texto
    var nombreCancion = document.getElementById("txtNombreCancion").value;

    // Creamos la URL de la solicitud a la API de búsqueda de Google
    var apiKey = "AIzaSyD0pnoN8kCr0qtdgXbYNuJq_k_Kq1rRrj8";
    var cx = "f180285ff9ce54b78";
    var query = "quién canta " + nombreCancion;
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" + apiKey + "&cx=" + cx + "&q=" + encodeURIComponent(query);

    // Hacemos la solicitud a la API de búsqueda de Google con fetch
    fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        // Obtenemos el primer resultado de la búsqueda
    var resultado = data.items[0];

    // Mostramos el título y la descripción del resultado en el div
    var div = document.getElementById("resultado");
    div.innerHTML = "<h2>" + resultado.title + "</h2>" + "<p>" + resultado.snippet + "</p>";
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta - Copia y pega el código, luego sombreas el texto del código (Seleccionalo) mientras esta sombreado arriba en la barra de herramientas de editación le das al botón con el icono `{ }` y asi el texto tomara formato de código.

Comment: Y borra la respuesta de abajo, ese es solo espacio para respuestas si tienes alguna duda o pregunta la haces aquí en comentarios.

Comment: Debajo del catch o sea al final te falta una llave `}`, la llave que cierra la función, a mí me funciona bien no más me fallaba en eso.

Answer (score 0):

***Primer error***: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

[Referencia](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input#:%7E:text=The%20%22Uncaught%20SyntaxError%20Unexpected%20end,an%20empty%20response%20with%20JSON.)

> El error "Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected end of input" se produce
> para 3 principales Razones:
>
> Olvidar un paréntesis de cierre, corchete o cita.
>
> Intentando analizar una respuesta vacía con o `.JSON.parse()`
> `$.parseJSON`
>
> Obtener una respuesta o ninguna respuesta de un servidor
> e intentar para analizarlo como `JSON.text/html`

***Segundo error:*** `Uncaught ReferenceError: buscarCancion is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick`

Según lo que investigue tiene que ver con las etiquetas `<script></script>` aunque no le vi problema alguna diría que es derivado del primer error.

```
function buscarCancion() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        //...
      })
      .then(function(data) {
       //...
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
       //...
    })
}// <--- Llave que faltaba
```

Comment: Gracias, donde faltaría esa llave?

Comment: Ya lo corregí. Gracias!!